# Chrome Extension: How to inject a content script into an iframe's page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm working on a Chrome extension that among other things supports a page with multiple dynamically created iframes in it, pointing to multiple different domains. I need to load a content script into each of those iframes, ideally without loading it into every page.

There's a separate content script that's running on all those iframe pages, which can detect that it's in an applicable iframe, and I'd like it to load this other content script. After [some wrangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49542628/chrome-extension-sending-a-message-to-the-page-loaded-in-a-specific-iframe), it can get the frameId of that iframe, but chrome.tabs.executeScript() takes only tabId, not frameId, so the script loads in the top-level page, not the desired iframe.

Note that the script I want to inject needs to run as a content script, with access to the available Chrome APIs.

Is it possible to do this? How?

---

**Update:** Ach, you're of course right wOxxOm, that "frameId can be specified inside executeScript's second parameter". Thank you again, make that an answer and I'll accept it. I need to read more carefully, apparently. I'm a long-time programmer, but new to Chrome extensions, there's a lot to absorb.

Secondary question: It appears that I need to add `<all_urls>` or `http://*/*` and `https://*/*`, permission to the manifest for this to be allowed. The main content_script that's doing this has similar match patterns, and I could add this secondary script there too, but it's actually only needed for pages shown in these iframes, so this seems better to me. Are there other downsides to doing it this way, or is there some better approach, other than xhr/eval?

Comment: frameId can be specified inside executeScript's second parameter, see the documentation. Alternatively you can use the evil `eval` in your content script: first xhr/fetch the additional content script, then eval it.

Comment: @wOxxOm, updated the question with your reply, and a follow-up question.

Comment: Yes, executeScript can run only on permitted URLs (for example, those declared in permissions key or in content_scripts -> matches key). The only downside is that the permission warning prior to installation will say your extension needs to access all sites. The alternative is to use [optional permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions).

Comment: Optional permissions won't fly, this part of the extension won't work at all without that script. I either need to load it always via the manifest, or in code. The main content script has "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"]. Will that give the same warning on installation? If so, there's no additional penalty for this piece. Overall, it was you, would you do xhr/eval, or this?

Comment: The warning in your case won't change ([more info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings)). As for xhr+eval inside a content script, it is a solution for the case when those iframes already run a content script so it's up to you to decide.